# jquery serialize ignoring type="number" fields

Tags: jquery, serialization, field, numeric

I've been trying to work this one out with no success hence turning to the brains here to please advise me.

I have a long form which I'm submitting to a php script with jquery serialize.

What's strange is that it seems to be skipping any field of type="number"

hence

```
<input type="number" class='form-control' id='a2-employedannualincome' name='a2-employedannualincome'>
```

gets skipped, if I change it to

```
<input type="text" class='form-control' id='a2-employedannualincome' name='a2-employedannualincome'>
```

it comes through perfectly.

What's going wrong as it's missing loads of fields out of a long wizard type form?

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mcve] that reproduces problem. Click on `<>` in question editor to create a *"stack-snippet"* that will run right in this page

Comment: Note the basics of `serialize()` on that input work fine here https://jsfiddle.net/dmh6kpk7/

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help, I found the issue and was my fault for not remembering my code! I had another plugin I was using to serialize checkbox values and hadn't changed it correctly to allow other types

https://tdanemar.wordpress.com/2010/08/24/jquery-serialize-method-and-checkboxes/